# 4D mobile: pessimistic locking not working

Tags: locking, wakanda, 4d-database

I'm trying to make use of the `entity.lock()` method on wakanda to lock a record to my 4D users, as described in the documentation for [`lock()`](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Wakanda/0.Beta/lock.301-1074685.en.html).

Yet, when applying the code given in the doc, the `lock()` method always return false, and 4D can happily edit the record Wakanda is trying to lock out.

I'm using 4D 14.3 and Wakanda 11.197492.

Anybody else having the same problem?

Comment: Is the record already locked or in read-only mode for the current wakanda client? Without attempting to lock the record, does editing it from Wakanda actually work and is the modified record updated in 4D after the edit?

Comment: Hi Tim, the record is not already locked in wakanda, it is in read-write for the current wakanda client as I can edit the record. Without attempting to lock the record, editing the record from wakanda works and the changes are updated in 4D after the edit.

Comment: UPDATE: I've just tried the same test with 4D 15.2, and the lock() method is working as expected: the record is locked to all 4D users. So it appears it's an issue fixed between 14.3 and 15.2.

Comment: V14.3 is very old.  What about v14.5...?

Comment: I have tried with 14.5. The issue is still there... :(

Comment: Well then if v15 fixes it I think that is a better solution anyways.